# how to call a function on a something append

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a tab when user click on button a new is generated. I want when user click on this tab a function call which is like

```
onclick('+reportname+','+report type+')

onclick("'+reportname+'","'+report type+'")
```

I tried in both way but function is not working

here is my code

```
 filename = $.trim($(elem).closest('td').find('.lblReportfileName').text());
 ReportType = $.trim($(elem).closest('tr').find('.ReportType').text());

 $(".ReportTiles").append('<div class="widgetsReportTiles"  style="background-color:#02a7f9b8;color:black" id="widgetsReportTilesId">' 
+ '<span class="reportType" onclick="OpenReportTab("'+filename+'","'+ReportType+'","")">' + filename + '</span>' 
+ '<span class="reportcloseicon" onclick="HideReportTile(this)">' + "x" + '</span>' + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
$(".ReportTiles").on('click','.OpenReportTab',function(){
    filename = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.lblReportfileName').text());
    ReportType = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.ReportType').text());
    OpenReportTab(filename,ReportType)
})
```

and remove onclick from append

Comment: I want to store parameters in function on every new tab
like when user click on Apple in function stores 
OpenReportTab(Apple,Fruits)

if click on bike 
OpenReportTab(Bike,vehicle )

Comment: You are already saving parameters for each append. You just need to take and pass to function dynamically. On click of OpenReportTab, you just need to pass respective parameters to function.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the advantage of [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var ReportType = 'rType';
var filename = 'fname';
var x = 'x123';

$(".ReportTiles").append(`<div class="widgetsReportTiles"  style="background-color:#02a7f9b8;color:black" id="widgetsReportTilesId"> 
<span class="reportType" onclick="OpenReportTab('${filename}','${ReportType}','')">${filename}</span>
<span class="reportcloseicon" onclick="HideReportTile(this)">${x}</span></div>`);

function OpenReportTab(f, r){
  console.log(f +'::::'+ r);
}
function HideReportTile(t){
  console.log(t.textContent);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ReportTiles"></div>
```